# $_SESSOIN вместо $_GET

Tags: php, база-данных, post, get, сессия

В процессе разработки своего небольшого проекта пришла в голову мысль использовать $_SESSION вместо $_GET для занесения в них например id записей из БД и с дальнейшим использованием этого id на других страницах.

Уважаемые специалисты, как вы считаете, на сколько данный подход будет правильным и надёжным с точки зрения безопасности сайта. Повысит ли это как-то надёжность сайта при взломе например или прочих любых действий?

Comment: Есть такая поговорка, "дурная голова ногам покоя не даёт". Это, в целом, всё, что считают уважаемые специалисты по поводу подобный идей. Креативность, с одной стороны, это конечно хорошо, но с другой нужно всегда придерживаться простого правила - решать надо всегда только реальные проблемы, и никогда не забивать себе голову воображаемыми

Comment: Смотря каких записей. В плане безопасности неважно - это как спрашивать, чем безопасней гвозди забивать - квадратным молотком или цилиндрическим. Вообще неплохо бы конкретизировать пример. Если хотите повысить безопасность сайте - юзайте шифрование, обфускацию и др. средства повышения безопасности, а не сравнивайте различные контейнеры для данных, что передаются одним и тем же протоколом.

Answer (score -3):

Если вы хотите отказаться от $_GET что бы скрыть данные с URL то лучше воспользоваться $_POST